# Use friend class in gcc

Tags: c++, class, gcc, friend, forward-declaration

I have this class that compiles in VC14, but when I try to compile in gcc 4.8.5, it doesn't work, I get "error: C was not declared in this scope".

```
class A
{

};

class B : public A
{
   friend class C;
   friend class D;
private:
   class BB
   {
      std::list<C> c;
      std::list<D> d;
   };
};

class C : public B::BB
{

};

class D : public B::BB
{

};
```

I tried to forward declare "class C" before the definition of class B, but it gives me an error because it doesn't have the same definition as "class C : public B::BB", and I can't put that definition because BB is private... I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Comment: `friend class BB { ...` is this a typo? You cannot declare/implement a class as friend like that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. (Also, "C++11" is not a compiler.)

Comment: Yes was a typo, sorry about that

Comment: IMHO, `friend` classes add complexity.  Can you redesign without needing `friend`?

Comment: I recommend against nested classes; the increase the complexity of the code (in both reading and typing).

Comment: This doesn't compile with any C++ compiler because of ..., missing semicolons, missing definition of List etc. This is not real code. We have no idea what is the real problem because we don't get to see the real code.

Comment: I fixed the code so that it works. I'm not allowed to change the original code, which was originally only for VC compiler, but now I'm porting the code to linux, and I get this error, and I can't share the real code because it's not my code.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declarations that use `friend` are different from other forward declarations. Writing `friend class C;` within the definition of `B` declares that there *is* a class called `C` in the enclosing namespace (*i.e.,* the global namespace) but does not actually introduce the name `C` into that scope. Therefore, you can't write something like `List<C>` because the name `C` cannot be found. You should do this:

```
class C;
class D;
class B : public A
{
   friend class C;
   friend class D;
private:
   class BB
   {
      List<C> c;
      List<D> d;
   }
}
```

The namespace-scope declarations actually introduce the names `C` and `D` into the global scope. Then, the friend declarations make those classes friends of `B`.

Comment: Why does it "compile in C++11" (whatever that means)? Could VS have some non-conformance here? Might be a valued addition to the answer though I think we need a better question first.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you do

```
List<C> c;
List<D> d;
```

the compiler has no idea what `C` and `D` are--you haven't declared/implemented them yet!

You don't have to completely implement them, but you'll need to at least tell the compiler they're class that'll be implemented at some point. You can do that with:

```
class C;
class D;
```

Full working example (with some minor fixes like adding semicolons to make it compile): [ideone](https://ideone.com/G4OOj7)

Comment: I tried to do this, same as in your example, and I'm able to compile it in gcc 8, but not in gcc 4.8.5. It says that ‘class B::BB' is private. Is it because of the compiler version?

Comment: The full error is "class B::BB’ is private within this context 'class C : public B::BB'".